# Mostrar el total de veces que un producto se a comprado a cualquier usuario en Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, count, elementor

Quiero mostrar el total de veces que un producto se ha comprado a cualquier usuario (este o no registrado) en la pagina del producto en cuestion, para esto me base y modifique un poco el codigo que dieron en esta pregunta [Display the total purchase count of a specific product for customer in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999725/display-the-total-purchase-count-of-a-specific-product-for-customer-in-woocommer) pero por alguna razon cuando uso este codigo con la modificacion y actualizo la pagina de wordpress (con elementor) me muestra el siguiente mensaje [image: No se pudo cargar la vista previa] ademas cuando ingreso a mi web desde una ventana incognito (como un usuario que visita la pagina) me doy cuenta que el responsive no funciona y sale un error donde deberia estar el shortcode que dice

```
"Ha habido un error crítico en tu web.

Aprende más sobre la depuración en WordPress."
```

Tambien intente buscar las [Tablas de woocommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description#table-woocommerce_order_itemmeta) para poder hacer una consulta simple y ver si me devolvia el resultado deseado pero tampoco lo logre a continuacion muestro el codigo con el que intente hacer la consulta simple

```
function wc_product_sold_count( $product_id ) 
{    
    global $wpdb;

    // The SQL request
    $units_bought = $wpdb->get_var
    ("
        Select umeta_id from wp_usermeta
     ");

    foreach($units_bought as $row) 
    {
         echo 'Name: '.$row->umeta_id.'<br/>';
    }
}

// The shortcode from this function
add_shortcode('product_sold_count', 'shortcode_product_sold_count');

function shortcode_product_sold_count( $atts ) 
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_sold_count' );

    return wc_product_sold_count( $atts['id'] );
}
```

Este es el codigo modificado que intento usar para mostrar la cantidad de productos en la pagina

```
function wc_product_sold_count( $product_id ) 
{
// Only for logged in users
//if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return; // Exit for non logged users

//$user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Current User ID

// The SQL request
$units_bought = $wpdb->get_var( "
    SELECT SUM(woim2.meta_value)
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta woim2 ON woi.order_item_id = woim2.order_item_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p ON woi.order_id = p.ID
    WHERE woi.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'
    AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
    AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
    AND woim.meta_key = '_product_id'
    AND woim.meta_value = '$product_id'
    AND woim2.meta_key = '_qty'
");

// Display count if is greater than zero
if( $units_bought > 0 ) {
    $label = __( 'Units bought' , 'woocommerce' ); // Label

        // Returned output
        return '<p class="units-bought"><strong>' . $label . ': </strong>' . $units_bought . '</p>';
    }
}

// The shortcode from this function
add_shortcode('product_sold_count', 'shortcode_product_sold_count');
function shortcode_product_sold_count( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_sold_count' );

    return wc_product_sold_count( $atts['id'] );
}
```

Elimine las lineas que incluyen la informacion del usuario `if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;`, `$user_id = get_current_user_id();`, `INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm ON woi.order_id = pm.post_id`, `AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'` y `AND pm.meta_value = '$user_id'` ya que no es de mi interes mostrar por usuario, si no independientemente de este

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que ves al intentar editar en elementor ( o en la página de incógnito ) es indicativo de que hubo un error de php en el código.

Por otro lado, [desde versión 3.0 hay disponible un método](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_get_total_sales) para obtener las ventas totales de un producto.

Teniendo disponible el producto:

```php
$cantidad = $product->get_total_sales();
```

Teniendo el id de producto:

```php
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$cantidad = $product->get_total_sales();
```

En forma de shortcode hacemos opcional el atributo id, así lo podes usar en el template de single product.

```php
// muestra número de ventas totales por producto
// si no se define el id se intenta averiguar por el global $product
// [EMPsalescount id=4082]
add_shortcode('EMPsalescount', 'soes410475_showsalescount_shortcode');
function soes410475_showsalescount_shortcode( $atts = [], $content = null, $tag ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
    [
      'id' => NULL,
    ], $atts
  );

  $product_id = absint( $atts['id'] );
  $cantidad = 0;
  $output = '';

  if ( 0 < $product_id ) {
    // si hay un id válido buscamos el producto por id
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
  } else {
    // si no hay id pedimos el global
    global $product;
  }
  // si hay producto definido o encontrado verificamos que tenga el método
  if (
    $product &&
    method_exists( $product, 'get_total_sales' )
  ){
    $cantidad = $product->get_total_sales();
  }
  // si hay cantidad renderizamos el texto
  if ( $cantidad ) {
    // empieza captura de buffer
    ob_start();
    ?><p class=units-sold><strong><?php echo sprintf(
      __( '%s unidades vendidas', 'woocommerce' ),
      $cantidad
    );?></strong></p><?php
    // termina captura de buffer
    $output = ob_get_clean();
  }
  // retorna cadena vacía o el html del texto de cantidad
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me funciono perfectamente!